# Show that norm of a functional is continuous

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

This question is based on Lemma 3.3, page 6 in this paper: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1106.0622v4.pdf
I changed the notation quite a lot, but it should be a one-to-one correspondence.

---

$S(x)$ is a compact manifold for each $x \in [0,T]$.

Fix $s \in [0,T]$. Let $t \in [0,T]$. Suppose $f(t,s):H^{-1}(S(s)) \to H^{-1}(S(t))$ (linear functional),  with the property that $f(t,t)$ is the identity for any $t$, and suppose the following holds:

$$\frac{1}{1+|s-t|}\lVert u\rVert_{H^{-1}(S(s))} \leq \lVert f(t,s)u \rVert_{H^{-1}(S(t))} \leq \frac{1}{1-|s-t|}\lVert u\rVert_{H^{-1}(S(s))}$$

It might be helpful to know the adjoint of $f(s,t)$, written $f(s,t)^*:H^1(S(s)) \to H^1(S(t))$ has the property that $\lVert f(s,t)^*v \rVert_{H^1(S(t))}$ is continuous as a function of $t$.

**The task is to show that $\lVert f(t,s)u \rVert_{H^{-1}(S(t))}$ is continuous as a function of $t$.**

Clearly we can see that it is continuous at $t=s$. But how about apart from $s$? How to see that it is continuous?

Comment: You mean continuous when $u$ is fixed, right?

Comment: Do you mean, show that $\|f(t,s)u\|_{H^{-1}(S(t))}$ is continuous in $t$? Because you can't define the $H^{-1}(S(s))$ norm of that quantity, unless you know something about $S(x)$.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo Yeah, $u \in H^{-1}(S(s))$ is fixed.

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong Sorry, you're right, it should be S(t) in that norm. I'll edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The operators in question are defined in "Lemma and Definition 3.2" as pullbacks by diffeomorphisms $\Phi_t^s : \Gamma(s)\to \Gamma(t)$. ($S$ is $\Gamma$ in the paper). Said diffeomorphisms are flow maps of a (smooth, time-dependent) field (Assumption 2.1), which implies the composition rule $\Phi_u^t \circ \Phi_t^s = \Phi_u^s$. The composition rule passes to pullbacks $\phi_t^s : H^1(\Gamma(t)) \to H^1(\Gamma(s)) $ and their adjoints $(\phi_t^s)^*: H^{-1}(\Gamma(s)) \to H^{-1}(\Gamma(t))$.

Hence, the small-time estimate quoted in the original post is enough to obtain the continuity. It goes like this: 
$$\|(\phi_{t+\Delta t}^s)^* v\| = \|(\phi_{t+\Delta t}^t)^* ((\phi_t^s)^* v)\| 
\approx \|(\phi_t^s)^* v\| $$
where $\approx $ hides multiplicative constants that tend to $1$ as $\Delta t\to 0$.

The text below was written for an earlier version of the question, which lacked much of necessary context.

---

This looks like a counterexample... Let all $S(x)$ be the same compact manifold $S$. For $t,s\in [0,T]$ define $$\mu(t,s)=\begin{cases}1  \ &\text{ if } t\in \mathbb Q \\ \max(1,|s-t|) \ &\text{ if } t\notin \mathbb Q\end{cases}$$
This function is continuous in the second variable but not in the first.

Let $f(t,s)$ be the scalar operator that multiplies each function  by the constant $\mu(t,s)$, that is, $f(t,s)u=\mu(t,s)u$. The norm bounds on $\|f(t,s)u\|$ hold. Of course, $\|f(t,s)u\|$ is badly discontinuous with respect to $t$ when $|s-t|>1$.

The  adjoint operator $f(s,t)^*$ is the multiplication by $\mu(s,t)$. The norm $\|f(s,t)^*u\|$ is continuous with respect to $t$ because the function $t\mapsto \mu(s,t)$ is continuous.

Comment: Thanks. The thing is I got this from a paper so I assumed it was true (though I left out some details in my post which may have been necessary).

Comment: @soup They may well have been necessary. Do the operators form a (semi-)group, by any chance? My suggestion is to always  include a reference when asking a question about something in the literature. Quite often,  questions of this kind omit important information, precisely because the OP did not see how it is relevant.

Comment: Sorry about that. There is no semigroup stuff (at least not on the surface). I'll edit my main post. Anyway, unless somebody answers in the affirmative I'm happy to give you the bounty :P

Comment: @soup The linear operators are pullbacks by [time-dependent flow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_%28mathematics%29#Time-dependent_ordinary_differential_equations). You'd have a group if it was time-independent. As it is, you still have the composition rule: see the edited version.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @soup I remember you asking multiple questions involving families of compact manifolds. If they also came from reading papers (and you are still looking for answers), you may want to edit them to add appropriate references, as you did here.

Comment: I think those questions have been resolved, but you're right, I will do in the future.

Comment: @soup If, for example, [Is this a valid proof? (integral, homeomorphism, calculus)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/256680/is-this-a-valid-proof-integral-homeomorphism-calculus) was resolved, you should indicate so (either by editing the question title, or by posting a short answer of your own). Otherwise someone may be wasting their time trying to come up with an answer you no longer need.